# Python - reading huge file

Tags: python

I have the following code that tries to process a huge file with multiple xml elements.

```
from shutil import copyfile
files_with_companies_mentions=[]
# code that reads the file line by line
def read_the_file(file_to_read):
    list_of_files_to_keep=[]
    f = open('huge_file.nml','r')
    lines=f.readlines()
    print("2. I GET HERE ")
    len_lines = len(lines)
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        j=i
        if '<?xml version="1.0"' in lines[i]:
            next_line = lines[i+1]
            write_f = open('temp_files/myfile_'+str(i)+'.nml', 'w')
            write_f.write(lines[i])
            while '</doc>' not in next_line:
                write_f.write(next_line)
                j=j+1
                next_line = lines[j]
            write_f.write(next_line)    
            write_f.close()
            list_of_files_to_keep.append(write_f.name)
    return list_of_files_to_keep
```

The file is over 700 MB large, with over 20 million rows. Is there a better way to handle it?

As you can see I need to reference to the previous and the next lines with an indicator variable such as `i`.

The problem I am facing is that it is very slow. It takes more than 1 hour for every file and I have multiple of these.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? disk space?

Comment: It is very slow. I edited my original post.

Comment: How about parallel processing to work on several of these files at the same time?

Comment: You can do 'for line in f:' and just step through the lines one at a time on demand without reading them all into memory first. You'd need to rework the logic that looks for </doc> by setting a boolean flag to indicate whether you're looking for it or not though.

Comment: can you give me an answer with code so that I can try it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294146/python-fastest-way-to-process-large-file

From the link, this is the first thing you should do to improve your code: `with open() as infile: for line in infile:`

Comment: You could try reading it in lazily so it's not all in memory at once. If your computers getting short on memory, that could be causing it to slow down.

Comment: @adrCoder I added a code template to show you how to parallelize. You can do that, perhaps in conojuinction with other suggestions from the comments about the file I/O.

Comment: Reading the whole file in the memory and then jumping around that memory isn't so efficient.

Comment: Looks like you are looping over the whole file more than once. `for i in range(0,len(lines)):` and `while '</doc>' not in next_line:`

Comment: Can you guys give me a proper answer below with example of code I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parallel processing for speeding up, using the [`joblib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/joblib) package. Assuming you have a list of files called `files`, the structure would be as follows:

```
import ...
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def read_the_file(file):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    n = 8 # number of processors
    Parallel(n_jobs=n)(delayed(read_the_file)(file) for file in files)
```

Comment: I fear that I/O is the bottleneck. Parallel processing won't help a lot.

Comment: I agree - perhaps this can be used together with improving the file I/O aspect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't determine the total number of lines on its own or read the whole file at once
if you dont need to. Use a loop like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python) and you'll already save some time.
Plus consider this for usage of `readlines()` http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.de/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html.

Considering you're working with XML elements maybe consider using a lib that makes this easier. especially for the writing.

Answer (score 0):

1. suggestion: make use of a context manager:

   ```
   with open(filename, 'r') as file:
       ...
   ```
2. suggestion: do the reading and processing junk-wise (currently, you are reading the file in a single step, just afterwards you go over the list "line by line"):

   ```
   for chunk in file.read(number_of_bytes_to_read):
       my_function(chunk)
   ```

Of course this way you have to look out for correct xml tag start/ends.

Alternative: look for an XML Parser package. I am quite certain there is one that can process files chunk-wise, with correct tag-handling included.